# Why @Configuration annotation is removed from @EnableWebSecurity class in Spring Security 6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have recently migrated my Spring Boot application from `Spring Security 5` to `Spring Security 6`.
Usually, we use the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation in the configuration class to enable web security. An interesting thing I have noticed in Spring Security 6 is they have removed the @Configuration annotation from the @EnableWebSecurity class.

I've added the source code for the @EnableWebSecurity from [Spring Security 5](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.7.8/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableWebSecurity.html) and [Spring Security 6](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableWebSecurity.html) for ease of reference.

```
// Spring Security 5
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(TYPE)
@Documented
@Import({WebSecurityConfiguration.class,org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.SpringWebMvcImportSelector.class,org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ImportSelector.class,org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.class})
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
@Configuration
public @interface EnableWebSecurity

// Spring Security 6
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(TYPE)
@Documented
@Import({WebSecurityConfiguration.class,org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.SpringWebMvcImportSelector.class,org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ImportSelector.class,org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.class})
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
public @interface EnableWebSecurity
```

What I'm curious about is, what would be the reason behind removing the @Configuration annotation in Spring Security 6?

Edit: I have seen [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3014) mentioning @Configuration annotation is no longer needed for @Enable* annotations. But anyways, it's removed in Spring Security 6.

Comment: Because non of the other `@Enable*` annotations included `@Configuration`. This one was the odd one out. So now it is aligned with all other `@Enable*` annotations again and you yourself need to add `@Configuration` to mark a configuration class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because non of the other `@Enable*` annotations included `@Configuration`. This one was the odd one out. So now it is aligned with all other `@Enable*` annotations again and you yourself need to add `@Configuration` to mark a configuration class.

See als [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6613) related to the remove containing the reason why. The [PR for this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/11653) contains the changes.